# Why does the transition happen at the last index when removing element from array in Vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm making a simple todo list to learn Vue.

I am following this approach to add/remove an element from the list:
[Vue.js guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Entering-Leaving-Transitions)

When I remove an element from the array I would expect that element to disappear and then the other elements under it to take its space. But in my case the elements are shifted up and then the last element of the list (which has been "copied" one position up) is removed.

**Problem:** element removed correctly but transition wrong.

**Reproducing problem:** click remove on one of the items and look at the end of the list.

**JSFiddle:** [link](https://jsfiddle.net/ashtr0nauta/o9fbw0re/203/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="todoList">
<h1>todos </h1>
<input type="text" v-model="newItemText" class="new-todo" autofocus placeholder="What needs to be done?" @keyup.enter="addTodo">
<ul>
    <transition-group name="list" >
        <li v-for="(data, index) in todoList" v-bind:key="index">
            {{data.text}}
            <span class="remove-btn" v-on:click="removeItem(index)"> remove </span>
        </li>
    </transition-group>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
<style>
.list-enter-active,
.list-leave-active {
    transition: all 1s;
}

.list-enter,
.list-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(30px);
}
```

**JS:**

```
 var app = new Vue({
 
  el: "#todoList",
  data: {
    delete: '',
    newItemText: '',
    todoList: [
        {text: '0'},
        {text: '1'},
        {text: '2'},
        {text: '3'},
        {text: '4'},
        {text: '5'},
        {text: '6'},
        {text: '7'}
    ]
    
  },
  methods: {
    addTodo: function(){
            /* this.todoList.reverse(); */
            if(this.newItemText != ''){
                this.todoList.push({text: this.newItemText});
               /*  this.todoList.splice(0,0,{text: this.newItemText}); */
            }
            this.newItemText = '';
            /* this.todoList.reverse(); */
        },
    
    removeItem: function(index) {
        console.log(index);
        this.todoList.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
  
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your choice of `key`.

Vue uses the `key` to determine which VNodes are equivalent from one render to the next. As you're using `index` it pairs up the wrong nodes for the array entries and when there's no partner found for the final node it removes that.

So initially you have nodes with keys 0 to 7. You then remove the array item at index 4. But when Vue updates the rendering it doesn't see that 4 has been removed. It just sees nodes with keys 0 to 6. As far as it can tell it is the node with key 7 that has been removed.

For a quick experiment, try using `:key="data.text"`. You'll see it now works but the `text` isn't a great choice of `key` as it isn't necessarily unique. You should probably add some sort of unique id to your array entries so you can use that instead.

Comment: So let me see if I understood correctly. One way to do this would be to keep a variable in data that holds the current index number, for example, and each time we add a list item, we also add an id to the list element that contains the current index. Then in our v-for loop we set the key to be `data.id`. Is this approach common practice? or is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: @ashrafs. Yes, assuming the index in your data is just a counter that is incremented by 1 each time then this would be a perfectly acceptable way to generate the temporary ids needed for these items. Something along these lines is common practice but it typically only applies in cases where the data is not being persisted to a server. For server-side persistence the server will usually provide an id that can be used instead, though even then local ids may be used to avoid waiting for the request to complete when creating a new item.